# Objective-C syntax - how to initialize an array that "lives" deep in an object hierarchy

Tags: objective-c, arrays, syntax

I think this sketch will add clarity to what I am trying to achieve.

Essentially, I want to create iPhone app that allows user to select a schoolDistrict from a tableview and the app will slide that view over and reveal the next tableview full of schools.  When they select a school, the next view displays the teachers, finally, when they select a teacher, it will display the courses taught by that teacher.

So, I am trying to construct some sample data for my viewtable "drilldown" and I am struggling to populate such a hierarchical data structure.

I'm hoping the sketch below helps.

https://skitch.com/aibkwik/rqu41/photo-feb-13-10-30-15-pm.jpg

---

original post follows:

UPDATED:   I am trying to alloc an array that is deeply embedded in an object hierarchy. The top object instance is call "thisYear" and it has an array in it called "courses". "courses" also contains, among other things, an array called scoreCatetories.  How would you initialize and add an object to the "scoreCategories" array? I've tried numerous things, including:

I'm trying all manner of combinations such as the one below - nothing is working.

```
...
[[thisYear courses] scoreCategories] = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[[[thisYear courses] scoreCategories] addObject:myNewObj]; 
...
```

I'm trying to load some sample data -  the code below is located in the
`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function of the appDelegate.

Here is the code snippet that is causing me grief.
Please see the .h files, further down in this post.

```
dGradeURin *thisYear;
thisYear = [[dGradeURin alloc] init];
[thisYear.howManyTerms initWithInteger: 4];
thisYear.gradeURin = @"Freshman";
//this paragraph compiles and runs fine
dCourse *tmpcourse;
tmpcourse = [[dCourse alloc] init];
tmpcourse.cName =@"Computer Science";
tmpcourse.school =@"Freedom High";
thisYear.courses = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[thisYear.courses addObject:tmpcourse];


dScoringCategory *tmpSC;
tmpSC =  [[dScoringCategory alloc] init];
tmpSC.name = @"Quizzes";

//these two lines are not working
[[thisYear courses] setScoreCategories:[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease]];
[[[thisYear courses] scoreCategories] addObject:tmpSC];     

//both the above lines compile with a warning:  NSMutableArray may not respond to -setScoreCategories
// when I run the program, the first line causes crash with an exception... See stack trace at far bottom
```

---

Here are the .h header file snippets for  each  interface object definitions, in essence...

```
@interface dGradeURin : NSObject {
    
    NSNumber *howManyTerms;
    NSString  *gradeURin;
    
    NSMutableArray *courses;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSNumber *howManyTerms;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *gradeURin;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray  *courses;

    @interface dCourse  : NSObject {
        NSString *cName;
        NSString *teacher;
        NSString *school;
        NSString *school_term;
        NSString *gradingMethod;
        NSNumber *whichterm;
        
        NSMutableArray  *scoreCategories;
    }
    
    @property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *cName;
    @property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *school;
    @property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *scoreCategories;
    
    @interface dScoringCategory : NSObject {
    NSString *name;
    NSMutableArray *scores;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *scores;

@interface dScore : NSObject {

    NSNumber    *score;
    NSDate      *scoreDate;
    NSString    *description;

}

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSDate *scoreDate;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSNumber *score;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *description;
```

---

Here is the stack trace

```
2011-02-13 21:49:43.559 GradeJanx[86526:40b] -[__NSArrayM setScoreCategories:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b76660
2011-02-13 21:49:43.561 GradeJanx[86526:40b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM setScoreCategories:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b76660'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00db0be9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f055c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00db26fb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00d22366 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00d21f22 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   GradeJanx                           0x00002c50 -[AppDelegate_iPhone application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 881
    6   UIKit                               0x002ba1fa -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1163
    7   UIKit                               0x002bc55e -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 439
    8   UIKit                               0x002c6db2 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1533
    9   UIKit                               0x002bf202 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
    10  UIKit                               0x002c4732 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    11  GraphicsServices                    0x016e6a36 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00d92064 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf26f7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00cef983 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00cef240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00cef161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    17  UIKit                               0x002bbfa8 -[UIApplication _run] + 636
    18  UIKit                               0x002c842e UIApplicationMain + 1160
    19  GradeJanx                           0x000028bc main + 102
    20  GradeJanx                           0x0000284d start + 53
```

Comment: Arrays in Objective C (and most other languages) can't contain 'called arrays'. They contain elements indexed by numbers (0, 1, 2, etc). So, structure of `thisYear` object isn't clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, this is all sorts of messed up, so let's just step back a little bit.  An array is an indexed set of objects.  An index is a non-negative integer that represents the location of an object.  Each object is accessible in the array by an index.  You can't do `[[thisYear courses] scoreCategories]` and expect anything to work, because you haven't actually provided an index to the object in the array.  You could do something like `[[thisYear courses] objectAtIndex:0]`, which would return the first element in the array.  You could also do `[[thisYear courses] objectAtIndex:1]`, which would return the second element in the array.

Whenever you insert an element into an `NSMutableArray`, it inserts it as the last object in the array.  For instance, if the `NSMutableArray` you're inserting your object into doesn't have any elements contained within it, the index of the element you're inserting is 0.  If it have 1 element in it, then the index of the element you're inserting would have an index of 1.

The code you're probably looking for is this:

```
NSMutableArray *scoreCategories = [NSMutableArray array];
[scoreCategories addObject:myNewObj];
[[thisYear courses] addObject:scoreCategories];
```

However, there are a lot of other problems with doing things this way.  Before proceeding any further, I'd recommend you spend some time with a good Objective-C [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430218150).

**Update**

Okay, let's take another look at this.  This is pretty tough without the context in which this code appears, but we'll try anyway.

```
dGradeURin *thisYear = [[[dGradeURin alloc] init] autorelease];

thisYear.howManyTerms = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:4];
thisYear.gradeURin = @"Freshman";

NSMutableArray *courses = [NSMutableArray array];

//set up a temporary course
dCourse *temporaryCourse = [[[dCourse alloc] init] autorelease];
temporaryCourse.cName = @"Computer Science";
temporaryCourse.school = @"Freedom High";
temporaryCourse.scoreCategories = [NSMutableArray array];

dScoringCategory *temporaryScoringCategory = [[[dScoringCategory alloc] init] autorelease];
temporaryScoringCategory.name = @"Quizzes";

[temporaryCourse.scoreCategories addObject:temporaryScoringCategory];

[courses addObject: temporaryCourse];
thisYear.courses = courses;
```

This first line creates an autoreleased object.  That means that at some point, the memory this object is taken up will be freed for use somewhere else.  If you don't free the memory of an object, then it will keep taking up memory, whether you ever use it or not.  For more about this (and you *really* need to understand it to use Objective-C), check out [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

A couple of other things.  If this is homework, and it looks like it might be from the content, then **be sure you tag it as homework**.  I don't mind helping you here because it looks like most of your problems are syntactic, but don't forget next time.

Second, I don't know where you got those classes, but assuming you're using the interfaces correctly, they appear to be poorly designed.  There's a lot of understanding required to make things work well rather than just work.  I'd still recommend reading that book I linked above if you really want to learn this stuff.

Comment: Hey brother.  Thanks for your help.  Your code above fixed me up perfectly.  I am new to this site and want to post things in the right place.  So please tell me where I should better post these types of questions.  I did not tag as homework since I've been out of school for about 30 years.  :)  I'm just keeping the mind fresh by laying some code.   I just ordered the book you suggested and already have it on my iPad.  Many thanks!

Comment: Hey, no problem dude.  You posted your question in the right spot.  It's always good to learn new things and keep your mind sharp.  Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
for (Course *course in thisYear.courses) {
  course.scoreCategories = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Huh? Where? If scoreCategories is a retained property, its fine. --edit: Oh wait, yeah. Screwed up my counting. Sorry. --edit2: Fixed post.

Comment: Or, not to be picky, but you could just use [NSMutableArray array]

Comment: @helixed @boltclock @nikitaRybak hey - thanks for your response.  I have posted more information.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a declared property (with the `@property` syntax), then you can use the dot notation to set the property value:

```
// This assumes that scoreCategories has either the 'retain' or 'copy' property;
// if it instead uses 'assign', then you'll need to retain this array.
[thisYear courses].scoreCategories = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:myNewObj, nil];
```

If it's not a declared property, just access it using the standard arrow notation:

```
[thisYear courses]->scoreCategories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:myNewObj, nil];
```

Comment: In the latter case, be careful that your memory is handled properly, as you are now leaking the instance scoreCategories was pointing to before.

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest approach, but anyway:

```
[[thisYear courses] setScoreCategories:[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease]];
[[[thisYear courses] scoreCategories] addObject:myNewObj];
```

Comment: I almost wrote the same thing, but if you read the top part, he said courses is an array.  Clearly there's a lot more problems here then there would first seem to be.

Comment: Right, calling -scoreCategories made me overlook that that was actually an NSArray. I second your recommendation above on finding a good Obj-C/Cocoa book!

Answer (score 0):

I hate being that guy, but this kind of deep inspection (borrowed term there, hah!) smells like bad design to me.
Here's what i would do:
Have a property `courses` of the `thisYear` object that get's populated when needed. `courses` is an array that contains `Course` objects.  The `Course` object has a property called `scoreCategories` and also a Method `addScoreCategory`. So for your code above, you'd do a

```
 Course * currentCourse = [[thisYear courses] objectAtIndex:0]; // assuming you want the first course
  if ([currentCourse isKindOfClass:[Course class]]) {
    [currentCourse addScoreCategory:myNewObj];
  }
```

In either the `addScoreCategory` or the init method of the `Course` class you'd create an NSMutableArray and assign it to the `scoreCategories` property.